# How firebase auth state persistence works in electron apps?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, electron, google-cloud-firestore

I am logging the user in using anonymous auth method in electron app and getting the user id and creating a document on firestore `users` collection. I have a security rule where the user can modify only his doc in users collection.

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
  allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
}
```

But I think firebase persist auth data using `localStorage` but how reliable is that? In this link `https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store/issues/17` he says-

> localStorage is not very fault tolerant, so if your app encounters an error and quits unexpectedly, you could lose the data.

If that happens I have to re-login anonymously again but I will end up losing all the data which exist in `firestore` which is connected to the previous user id. If somebody has done some workaround for this please help me.

I don't mind if the user loses all his data when he uninstalls and reinstalls the app again as he will know that, that is the expected behavior.